# Drag and drop for upload file not work on Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I integrated drag and drop functionality into my site simply by applying CSS and jQuery with the `change` function.

The code works in Firefox and Chrome but not in Edge. If I try to drag a file and drop it, nothing happens. On other browsers, however, if I drag and drop files in the upload window it works smoothly.

How is it that the drag and drop feature doesn't work in Edge?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form input').change(function() {
    $('form p').text(this.files.length + " file(s) selected");
  });
});
```

```css
form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -250px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 4px dashed #fff;
}

form p {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 170px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Arial;
}

form input {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

form button {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: #16a085;
  border: none;
  width: 508px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #117A60;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  outline: none;
}

form button:hover {
  background: #149174;
  color: #0C5645;
}

form button:active {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="upload.php" method="POST">
  <input type="file" multiple>
  <p>Drag your files here or click in this area.</p>
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```